# inconsistent SVG elements from Highcharts making tests fail with Geb/Selenium and PhantomJS

Tags: selenium, highcharts, phantomjs, geb

Having trouble explaining this:

My Geb/Selenium tests are making assertions on SVG `rect` element width/height generated by Highcharts.

The tests pass locally on Chrome/Windows, and pass on PhantomJS on a Linux CI environment. They fail when I run them on PhantomJS locally on Windows, though. The height seems to be a few pixels off - consistently, it is about 1 or 2 pixels different when I run locally on PhantomJS in Windows.  For example, my assertion that `rect.height=168` fails because it's `166`.

I have confirmed that it is the same version of PhantomJS in both environments.

What else could I be missing?  And what could cause Highcharts to generate different SVG in Chrome and PhantomJS?

I can isolate this from the test framework and execute with PhantomJS directly:

```
var webpage = require('webpage');
var page = webpage.create();
page.viewportSize = {width: 1280, height: 1024};

page.open("http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic", function(status) {
    var height = page.evaluate(function() {
      return jQuery('g.highcharts-series rect:nth(0)').attr('height');
    });
    console.log(height);
    phantom.exit(); 
});
```

This code will print `52` when run on Linux and `53` when Windows.

Comment: Might be related to the different DPI settings of linux (75), mac (72) and windows (96). If this is indeed it, you will need to change the constants in the source code and recompile it.

Comment: It feels like it could be some kind of rounding issue.  What I don't understand is why Chrome on Windows matches PhantomJS on Linux, but PhantomJS on Windows is different.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're going to test, but this could be a solution for adapting to rounding issues. Detect the underlying OS and setup a configuration object with dpi corrections per OS.

```js
var webpage = require('webpage'),
  page = webpage.create(),
  system = require('system'),
  os = system.os,
  correction = {
    mac: 1,
    windows: 1.019
  };

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1280,
  height: 1024
};

page.open("http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic", function(status) {
  var height = page.evaluate(function() {
    return jQuery('g.highcharts-series rect:nth(0)').attr('height');
  });

  console.log(Math.round(height * correction[os.name]));

  phantom.exit();
});
```